# AHK won't start Vagrant/Cmder on boot/reload?

Tags: autohotkey, vagrant, cmder

I have the following AHK script in my startup folder, <s>there's also a few shortcuts before this, they work but this bit doesn't,</s> any idea why I can't startup my dev environment on windows startup?

```
; if conemu's not running, start vagrant & cmder (conemu) on startup (or script re-start)
Process,Exist,ConEmu.exe
{ 
   If !errorlevel
   {
        RunWait "%comspec% /C vagrant up", C:\vagrant\ubuntu, Hide,
        Run "C:\cmder\Cmder.exe", "", Max
        return
    } else {
        return
    }
}
```

According to what I've read elsewhere, this is how it's done & I'm not sure why it doesn't work

EDIT: I've moved my code as suggested by @user3419297 below, it works better now, but it still doesn't work as expected. I get the following error:

```
Error: Failed attempt to launch program or document:
Action: <C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C vagrant up>
Params: <>

Specifically: The system cannot find the file specified
```

which is referencing `RunWait "%comspec% /C vagrant up", C:\vagrant\ubuntu, Hide,`

How would I run the `vagrant up` command in the correct folder using `cmd.exe`?

Comment: RunWait "%comspec% /C C:\vagrant\ubuntu\vagrant up", C:\vagrant\ubuntu, Hide,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any lines you want to execute immediately when the script starts should appear at the top of the script, prior to the first hotkey, hotstring, or Return. For details, see **[auto-execute section](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto)**.
https://autohotkey.com/docs/FAQ.htm#autoexec

Comment: Thanks, @user3419297, I've moved the bit of code to the auto-execute section, but it still won't run `vagrant up`, would you be so kind as to take a second look at my edited question?

Comment: Read https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm#Remarks how to run a program via Comspec.